# WPF: Show a cell is edited in bound DataGrid

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, datagrid, overriding

Im trying to change the background color of the edited cell in my bound DataGrid. For example, after the user changes the value in a cell, I will call mydatagrid.Items.Refresh() to update the rest of my column values and change the edited cell background to LightPink.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to play around with the DataGridBoundColumn [ElementStyle property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datagridboundcolumn.elementstyle(v=vs.110).aspx) to do what you want.

It may be easier to extend one of the DataGridColumns and use that in your grid. Might look something like this:

```
  class DataGridTextColumnEx : DataGridTextColumn
    {      
        protected override FrameworkElement GenerateElement(DataGridCell cell, object dataItem)
        {
            var element = base.GenerateElement(cell, dataItem);
            cell.Tag = dataItem;

            element.IsVisibleChanged += Element_IsVisibleChanged;

            return element;
        }

        private void Element_IsVisibleChanged(object sender, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            var textBlock = sender as TextBlock;
            var cell = textBlock.Parent as DataGridCell;
            var data = cell.Tag;
            if (textBlock.Visibility == Visibility.Visible)
            {
                //Use data to do validation...
                textBlock.Background = Brushes.LightPink;
            }
        }
    }
```